# bash Check for block of text

Tags: regex, string, bash, multiline

I want to execute a command if a block of text exists i.e.

```
if [ multiple line string exists ]; then
   <execute command>
fi
```

One of the multiple line strings in question is all of the following:

```
Which test would you like to run? 3

        [led.test]
        : This test will light LEDs 1 and 2
        :
        : LED1     LED2
        : --------------
        : ON       OFF
        : OFF      ON
        :
------> : Did the LEDs light up as indicated above? (y/n):n:
FAILED  : User indicates LEDs did not light up properly
```

A regex can be used for some of this text but I need to ensure this failure corresponds to this test. The FAILED line is common for all LED tests so that is why I was hoping to just do a search for the exact block of text.

How can I search for a multiline string? I was thinking about putting that string into a variable e.g.

```
string1="    Which test would you like to run? 3

        [led.test]
        : This test will light LEDs 1 and 2
        :
        : LED1     LED2
        : --------------
        : ON       OFF
        : OFF      ON
        :
------> : Did the LEDs light up as indicated above? (y/n):n:
FAILED  : User indicates LEDs did not light up properly"
```

and then someway of checking if string1 is in a file. If it exists then I will execute a command e.g. echo "String exists"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AmalMurali I am trying to code up a conditional statement to search for multiple line string in a file but am unable to do it.

Comment: OK, but what exactly are you trying to do? "*code up a conditional statement to search for multiple line string in a file*" isn't descriptive enough; at least to me.

Comment: I may be totaly wrong but: how about setting the text in a var and testing against it ? (including newlines and so on...) if what you wish to get is the exact match... I see no interest in regex

Comment: @AmalMurali If that multiple line string is found then execute a command

Comment: IMHO, the design, where you need match such string isn't the best. Try rethink the problem again, and choose better approach. Anyway, multiline matching is possible e.g. using `perl`.

Comment: `if [[ $(<file.txt) = *"$string1"* ]]; then` ...

Comment: If the `[led.test]` is a common header -- such that every other test will have a unique `[foo.test]` preceding it -- I'd look for and match on those strings, rather than on a larger block. Makes your implementation considerably less fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
string1="Which test would you like to run? 3

    \[led.test\]
    : This test will light LEDs 1 and 2
    :
    : LED1     LED2
    : --------------
    : ON       OFF
    : OFF      ON
    :
------> : Did the LEDs light up as indicated above? \(y/n\):n:
FAILED  : User indicates LEDs did not light up properly"

#Search the file for the string1 and assign the matching parts to search
search=`grep "${string1}" file.txt`

#If the string existed in the file, then search and string1 should match EXACTLY
if [ "${search}" = "${string1}" ]; then
    #DO STUFF 
    echo "string exists"
fi
```

This will only work if string1 is EXACTLY what will be in the file and there are no duplicates. If there are duplicates, you could pipe the `grep` result through `uniq`.

EDIT:
As  Charles Duffy pointed out, you have to be careful with any symbol that could be taken to be a regex expression. You can simply escape them with '\'

Comment: Better to use `grep -q` than `grep` -- more efficient, since it stops as soon as it finds a match rather than continuing to the end of the file -- and check the exit status, not the output.

Comment: There's also the danger of `grep` treating your string as a regular expression, or (as in fgrep mode) as a list of patterns rather than only one. For instance, `[led.test]` matches _any single character_ of `l`, `e`, `d`, `.`, or `t`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. `grep` does indeed get confused with `[]`

Comment: `-q` would be efficient, however it doesn't work correctly with multiline strings IE it would stop at the first matched line of the multiline string.

Comment: if `grep -q` does that, then checking whether `grep` outputs anything on a multiline match fails similarly -- it would have _some_ output if any line matches. Similarly, if it contains the text to be matched *but other content which matches any single line of the multiline string in addition*, you get false negatives. And if you have content that matches but with other lines between them, you get a false-positive match where you shouldn't have had one.

Comment: Yeah that is true. Checking if the output of `grep` matches the target string exactly, mitigates most false positive hits. As for false negatives, `uniq` could help filter out the extra matching lines. This solution is hacky as is though.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the entire file into the shell and doing a pattern match is inefficient, but works correctly in cases where `grep` doesn't:

```
if [[ $(<file.txt) = *"$string1"* ]]; then
```

Comment: And for files which require root access to read: `$(sudo cat file.txt)`